# Upload file from HTML5 web page to Node.js server using POST

Tags: node.js, html, formidable

Dears,

I want to implement file upload web page using HTML5 and Node.js based server.
Also I want not to use form tag in client side, and I need to send extra data to server about file information. I use customize HTTP header so that server can catch it.

Current my problem is that client can upload file to server, but server save file with additional data, such as HTTP header and boundary.

I think that server store ALL HTTP request from client side include HTTP header, file binary data and additional value such as boundary.

What can I do for storing only file data on server side?

Server is implemented using HTTP module, and current I can't change the main module for server now because many things are already implemented on server side.

Client side :

```
// HTML Code
<tr>
    <td><textarea id="customData1"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea id="customData2"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="file" id="uploadFile"></td>
    <td><button id="uploadFile" onclick="uploadFileToServer()">Upload</button</td>
</tr>

// JavaScript Code
function uploadFileToServer() {
    var file = document.getElementById("uploadFile").files[0];
    var uri = "/uploadFile";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();

    xhr.open("POST", uri, true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=\\\"Boundary\\\"");

    xhr.setRequestHeader("my-custom-data-one", document.getElementById("customData1").value);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("my-custom-data-two", document.getElementById("customData2").value);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("file-size", file.size);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("file-name", file.name);

    fd.append("myFile", file);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
</script>
```

I tried some methods but all not works.

Server side :

Basic server code)

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        // Need to add upload file code
    }
}).listen(PORT.Main);
```

Case 1) Use appending chunk data. But useless data (header / boundary) are also written.

```
 req.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log(data)
     fs.appendFileSync(filename, data)// += data;

 });

 req.on('end', function () {
     res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' })
     res.write('Upload Complete!\n');
     res.end();
 });
```

Case 2) Use writeStream. But useless data (header / boundary) are also written.

```
var file = './temp.file'
var downloadWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(file);
req.pipe(downloadWriteStream);
req.on('end', function () {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' })
    res.write('Upload Complete!\n');
    res.end();
});
```

Case 3) Use Formidable npm module, but it return error message : Error: MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = START_BOUNDARY

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.parse(req);

form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
    file.path = filename;
});

form.on('file', function (name, file) {
    console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);

    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' })
    res.write('Upload Complete!\n');
    res.end();
});
```

Thank you for reading this question and I am looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Please ignore about \\\"Boundary\\\"". Originally al HTML code is string value from server(not from HTML file). So it is just typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). It makes this super easy.

Client Example Code:

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

Server Example Code:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try it and use express-formiable to get more data from web page, but if I use mutler and express-formiable, then multer not works. How I can use it both?